# SQL updating tables recursively with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have a conversation table and conversation reply table:

conversation table:

```
+-------+-------+--------+
| cid   | u_1   | uid_2  |
+-------+-------+--------+
| 1     | 8     | 3      | 
| 2     | 8     | 5      |  
| 3     | 8     | 2      | 
+-------+-------+--------+
```

conversation_reply table:

```
+-------+-------+--------+--------+
| cr_id | reply | uid_fk | cid_fk |
+-------+-------+--------+--------+
| 1     |       | 8      | 1      |
| 2     |       | 8      | 11     |   
| 3     |       | 8      | 11     | 
+-------+-------+--------+--------+
```

I need to be able to update the conversation table with a new record if one doesn't exist when a new reply is created, however I get the following error:

```
Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
(`_db`.`conversation_reply`, CONSTRAINT `conversation_reply_ibfk_2` 
FOREIGN KEY (`cid_fk`) REFERENCES `conversation` (`cid`))
```

Any help much appreciated!!!!

**EDIT**

I have put the convo reply query into the create new convo query, it will create a new convo but still doesn't insert the reply:

```
if (!empty($_GET['conv_id'])) {

        $cid = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['conv_id']);
            echo $cid;

    }


if($user_one!=$user_two){

// Check convo doesn't already exist.

$q_exist= mysql_query("SELECT c_id FROM mc_conversation WHERE (user_one='$user_one' and user_two='$user_two') or (user_one='$user_two' and user_two='$user_one') ") or die(mysql_error());

if(mysql_num_rows($q_exist)==0) { 
    $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO mc_conversation (user_one,user_two,ip,time) VALUES ('$user_one','$user_two','$ip','$time')") or die(mysql_error());
    $q=mysql_query("SELECT c_id FROM mc_conversation WHERE user_one='$user_one' ORDER BY c_id DESC limit 1");
    $v=mysql_fetch_array($q);
    return $v['c_id'];
    $v_cid = $v['c_id'];

    // Insert reply.

    $qR= mysql_query("INSERT INTO mc_conversation_reply (user_id_fk,reply,ip,time,c_id_fk) VALUES ('$uid','$reply','$ip','$time','$v_cid')") or die(mysql_error());


// Convo already exists.

} else {


    $v=mysql_fetch_array($q_exist);
    return $v['c_id'];

   // Insert reply

    $qR= mysql_query("INSERT INTO mc_conversation_reply (user_id_fk,reply,ip,time,c_id_fk) VALUES ('$uid','$reply','$ip','$time','$cid')") or die(mysql_error());

    echo $cid;

}
```

}

Comment: you need to create parent records first. e.g. insert into `conversation` FIRST, then insert into the reply table.

Comment: Thanks, for some reason when I do it this way round, the conversation gets created but the reply doesn't get created...

Comment: I have added more code..

Comment: I can't see where you've defined the variable $cid in the else statement

Comment: Sorry, added it in now.

Comment: The problem is the "return" line in the else statement. See answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have called "return" in your else loop, which will end execution of the function, or if called from the global scope, execute the current script.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php
Try this:

```
// Insert reply
 $v=mysql_fetch_array($q_exist);
 $qR= mysql_query("INSERT INTO mc_conversation_reply (user_id_fk,reply,ip,time,c_id_fk) VALUES ('$uid','$reply','$ip','$time','$cid')") or die(mysql_error());
 echo $cid;
```

Comment: Thanks! What a silly mistake! Got rid of one return and shifted the other, seems to be working now! Thanks!

Comment: No worries. Easily done. Just remember to always put return at the end of your function (or at a point where you are happy for it to stop executing, such as at the end of an if/else statement).

Answer (score 0):

From the code that you have posted I think the problem is with the **return** statement.

The reply is not getting inserted because you have

```
return $v['c_id'];
```

before the INSERT query code. And if this code is inside a function, it will just return the value and not execute any further line.

You should have the return statement at the very end of the function / after doing all required operations. If it is for debugging purpose, you can use **echo** statement.

Comment: Thanks for your help, this was the case but gazareth discovered it first! Thanks though, you are right too!

Comment: Hey its okay, when I was typing the reply there was nobody pointed this mistake. I guess gazza was also typing simultaneously with me :) When I hit enter I was like WOW answer is already posted. Glad that you got what you need.